# predict function on the 'grplasso' package

Tags: r, package, lasso-regression

I use 'grplasso' package for train and test datasets. I find the best lambda (minimum AIC) by the fitting model on train dataset. This lambda name is 'lambdaopt'.

```
BestTrainFit <- grplasso(Outcome ~. , data = traindata, lambda = lambdaopt, model = LogReg(), center = TRUE,standardize = TRUE)
```

I want to calculate performance model on the test dataset. So, Which ways below corrected?
1. The calculation 'grplasso' model again by 'lambdaopt' on the test dataset

```
BestTestFit <- grplasso(Outcome ~. , data = testdata, lambda = lambdaopt, model = LogReg(), center = TRUE,standardize = TRUE)
p1 = BestTestFit$fitted
```

2. Using the 'predict' function on the 'grplasso' package

   p2 = predict(BestTrainFit,testdata,type = 'response')